# java variable scope, variable might not have been initialized

Tags: java, variables, scope

I am studying java, I know Java variable scope, such as class level, method level, block level.
However, when I try to practice the variable scope, I meet the error in my code.
my code is as following:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int c;
        for (int i=0; i <5; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            c = 100;
        }
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

when I run this code, it display the error: `the c variable might not have been initialized`, but when I change my code to the following:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int c=0;
        for (int i=0; i <5; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            c = 100;
        }
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

The code will print `100`.

How should I understand the scope in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java local variables are not initialized with a by default value (unlike, for example field of classes). From the language specification one ([§4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)) can read the following:

> **A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be explicitly given a value
> before it is used**, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment
> (§15.26), in a way that can be verified using the rules for definite
> assignment (§16 (Definite Assignment)).

Because it is explicitly set on the Java language specification the compiler will not try to (and should not) infer that the variable `c` will always be updated inside the loop:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int c;
        for (int i=0; i <5; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            c = 100;
        }
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

The compiler strictly enforces the standard and notifies you about having breaking one of its rules with the error:

```
"variable c might not have been initialized"
```

So even though your code can be formally proven to be valid, it is not the compiler *job* to try to analyze your application's *logic*, and neither does the rules of *local variable initialization* rely on that. The compiler checks if the variable `c` is initialized according to the *local variable initialization rules*, and *reacts* accordingly (*e.g.,* displaying a compilation error for the case of `int c;`).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a scope issue. Your variable c is method-scoped and available within whole main method. It's a compiler feature. At compile time it can't check that "for" cycle will run at least once to initialize the variable. That`s why it says that variable might not have been initialized when you are trying to print it. So c is available to print method, but compiler is not sure it was initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't make sure variable c is always initialized in the loop. For example if your code look like this:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int c;
        for (int i=0; i <0; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            c = 100;
        }
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Your code will never reach the loop then variable c never is initialized. That's why java language request you initialize a variable outside a loop if you use it outside a loop.